# Jsonpath get child node data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a sample json input below

```
{    
 "India":{
      "Attributes":{"Time":"2006-05-04T03:22:11.499Z"},
      "ActiveCity":{
           "profile":"Mumbai"
      },
      "CurrentCities":{
           "Mumbai":{"population":"121212121","Area":8},
           "Delhi":{"population":"121212121","Area":8},
           "Lonng":{"population":"121212121","Area":8}
      },
      "FeatureCities":{
           "NewMumbai":{"population":"121212121","Area":8},
           "NewDelhi":{"population":"121212121","Area":8},
           "NewLonng":{"population":"121212121","Area":8}
      }
 }
}
```

I am using the typescript to replace the currentCities section with only ActiveCity ,, example my ouput should look like this

```
{    
 "India":{
      "Attributes":{"Time":"2006-05-04T03:22:11.499Z"},
      "ActiveCity":{
           "profile":"Mumbai"
      },
      "CurrentCities":{
           "Mumbai":{"population":"121212121","Area":8}
      },
      "FeatureCities":{
           "NewMumbai":{"population":"121212121","Area":8},
           "NewDelhi":{"population":"121212121","Area":8},
           "NewLonng":{"population":"121212121","Area":8}
      }
 }
}
```

Using Jsonpath how can i achieve this in typescript ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the object in `currentCities` using the current value in:

```
 obj.India.CurrentCities[obj.India.ActiveCity.profile]
```

```js
let obj = {  "India": {    "Attributes": {      "Time": "2006-05-04T03:22:11.499Z"    },    "ActiveCity": {      "profile": "Mumbai"    },    "CurrentCities": {      "Mumbai": {        "population": "121212121",        "Area": 8      },      "Delhi": {        "population": "121212121",        "Area": 8      },      "Lonng": {        "population": "121212121",        "Area": 8      }    },    "FeatureCities": {      "NewMumbai": {        "population": "121212121",        "Area": 8      },      "NewDelhi": {        "population": "121212121",        "Area": 8      },      "NewLonng": {        "population": "121212121",        "Area": 8      }    }  }}

obj.India.CurrentCities = {[obj.India.ActiveCity.profile]: obj.India.CurrentCities[obj.India.ActiveCity.profile]}

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```